# How can I pass variables between invocations of GNU Make?

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I have a "parent" Makefile, and I am executing other Makefiles from it using `make -C`.

I am currently passing variables from the parent to its children by appending the variables to the `make` commands. This makes for quite a cumbersome pattern, for example:

> $(MAKE) -C $@ PREFIX="$(PREFIX)" CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS)" FOO="$(FOO)"

This makes for a lot of repetition, especially if there is a long list of $(MAKE) calls passing similar variables.

Is there a more elegant / optimal way to pass variables to a child invocation of `make`?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export them through the environment:

```
export PREFIX CXXFLAGS FOO
```

However, note that if these variables are actually set in the child makefile then this *will not* override those settings.

Comment: Unless you also use the `-e` flag on the sub-make that is.

Comment: Yes, but that can have other side-effects since it will also apply to ANY variable, including things like `PATH`, etc. which you might not want to override.  You can also write the child makefile to set those variables using `?=` so that they aren't reset if they already exist.